Why don't my prints show up on my 3D printer screen?
When I plug in my SD card into my 3D printer it reads that the SD card is in but doesn't display the prints. I need help please, I tried seeing if other people had this issue but haven't found it yet.

Ensure that the files on your SD card are of the format required for your printer. Edit your question to include the type of printer, the manufacturer and model name as well. In the filament printer world (FFF), one should have STL file format, while resin printers have a variety of formats, many specific to the printer.
I have a Longer™ brand printer which requires a specific file format as well as a specific folder location in the root of the card (Longer folder) in order to locate the files. My FFF printer cares only that the filename ends with .STL, although a malformed file will not print, of course.
Ensure also that the SD card is formatted to match the printer requirements. Some of the printers require that the card is formatted in FAT32 or exFAT, while others can handle more contemporary formats.

ok thanks will do
